# A problem with open Ubuntu software center

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center

I try to Update a program "brackets"  but I find this problem

```
(E:The package brackets needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.)
```

and I can't use the Ubuntu software center any more for any program. when I try to open it, it closes immediately.

I use Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I don't have any other OS with it.

So please what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you have installed the package via a deb file. You can repair your system easily via adding a PPA for *brackets*.

Using the commands below in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall brackets
```

---

*Breakdown*

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets`

  Add the PPA `ppa:webupd8team/brackets`
- `sudo apt-get update`

  Update your package database
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall brackets`

  Reinstall the package `brackets`